# Trying To Understand the Statement of Montel's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

**Montel's** Theorem States That:

**Theorem:**  Suppose $F$ be a family of holomorphic functions defined on a domain $D$  which is uniformly bounded on every compact subset of $D$.Then:

1.The family $F$ is equicontinuous on every compact subset of $D$

2.The Family $F$ is normal.

I don't understand why do we restrict on every compact subset of $D$.What does this theorem tells about Compact subset in the space of Holomorphic funtion ?Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**A reason** for to restrict on every compact subset of $D$ is because of kind of convergence that we work to complex functions.

For example, in complex analysis of functions in one variable, we want ever a uniform convergence, not pontual for functions. So when we considere the uniform convergence in compact parts, we win this is convergence is the same convergence of the uniform convergence topology.

So if we considere the set of continuous functions in $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, we have available some theorems of complete metric spaces, because this spaces is a Banach space with the norm of uniform convergence.